# Could not load file or assembly 'Mono.Cecil, Version=0.9.6.0; Initialize CMS application

Tags: kentico, kentico-11

I am running website on kentico 11.
When i'm trying to host and run locally through iis am getting following error.
When am running website directly from visual studio to browser. Then i am not getting this issue.

```
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Mono.Cecil, Version=0.9.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error:


Line 23: 
Line 24:         // Initialize CMS application. This method should not be called from custom code.
Line 25:         InitApplication();
Line 26:     }
Line 27: 

Source File: \CMS\App_Code\Global.asax.cs    Line: 25
Stack Trace:


[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Mono.Cecil, Version=0.9.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   CMS.Core.AssemblyDiscovery.IsAssemblyDiscoverable(String filePath) +0
   CMS.Core.AssemblyDiscovery.AddOnlyDiscoverableAssembly(ICollection`1 assemblies, Dictionary`2 preloadedAssemblies, AssemblyName assemblyName, String filePath) +131
   CMS.Core.AssemblyDiscovery.ExecuteGetAssemblies(Boolean onlyDiscoverable) +1192
   CMS.Core.AssemblyDiscovery.get_DiscoverableAssemblies() +31
   CMS.Core.TypeManager.PreInitializeTypes() +193
   CMS.Core.ModuleEntryManager.PreInit() +19
   CMS.Core.AppCore.PreInit() +146
   CMS.DataEngine.CMSApplication.PreInit() +164
   CMS.DataEngine.CMSHttpApplication.InitApplication() +24
   Global..cctor() in \CMS\App_Code\Global.asax.cs:25

[TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Global' threw an exception.]
   Global..ctor() +0
   ASP.global_asax..ctor() +48

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +142
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +107
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +1476
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes) +186
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture) +28
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.CreateNonPublicInstance(Type type, Object[] args) +82
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +174
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +347

[HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +552
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +122
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +737
```

any help is much appriciated

Answer (score 0):

This package is added to the solution via nugets. It referenced in packages.config. 
Clean and rebuild should help. Make sure the it exists in the /packages folder, if not restore nugets (or `Update-Package` ) for your solution and try to rebuild again. It must exists the /bin folder after the build.